# Возможно ли строить программы, используя изъявительное наклонение?

Tags: любой-язык

Верно ли утверждение, что действия, которые возможны при выполнении программы на традиционном языке, задаются в повелительной форме? Если да, возможно ли строить программы, используя изъявительное наклонение? А может они (действия в изъяв.накл.) уже используются в каких-либо языках программирования добавляя коду изящность и эффективность?

> *Изъявительное наклонение выражает действие, которое реально существует, существовало или будет существовать (купил, прочитал) ; глаголы в изъявительном наклонении имеют формы времени (настоящего, прошедшего и будущего) , лица (1,2 и 3) и числа (единственного или множественного);*

**UPD**. ([Непейвода Н. Н.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0,_%D0%9D%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9_%D0%9D%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), Скопин И. Н. Основания программирования. — 2003, стр 113)

P.S. Не привел источник сразу, потому как прямо не цитировал. Просто вынес на ruSO интересный для себя вопрос.

Comment: прочитал как "язвительное наклонение",  и уже бросился писать, что постоянно это делаю

Comment: Я не считаю, что в программах хоть как то обозначено наклонение. по сравнению с английским программы пишутся максимально сокращенными формулировками. части речи, которые могли бы однозначно определить наклонение отброшены. И простейшую конструкцию "if(i>0) print i;" я воспринимаю как "если i больше нуля то печатаю i", а не как "печатай i"

Comment: является ли описание схемы базы данных, или целевой системы в виде списка железа, ОС, доступных библиотек, схем взаимодействия компонентов изъявительным наклонением ?

Comment: Если не секрет, что это вы такое кур... эээ... читаете?... :)

Comment: Приведите пример кода, как вы это видите?

Comment: @Harry обновил вопрос.

Comment: Прочитал указанный вами источник. Там автор подробно отвечает на поставленный им вопрос. Хотя это даже не вопрос, это вводный текст для лучшего восприятия последующей темы про _нетрадиционные_ (читать видимо как _не императивные_) языки.  Наклонение само по себе (в том контексте) роли в общем то не играет. И ответ да, есть много не императивных языков, которые хороши для решения задач для которых они созданы и знать хотя бы про существование которых необходимо

Comment: Тестирование в стиле BDD, используя Cucumber  демонстрирует такое применение языка ([The Truth about BDD](https://sites.google.com/site/unclebobconsultingllc/the-truth-about-bdd)). Можно рассматривать это как пример декларативного стиля DSL.

Comment: [вот статья](https://habrahabr.ru/post/275013/), которая упоминает возможные причины, почему повествовательный стиль (Gherkin) даже для тестов не получил широкого распространения. Хотя разработка поддерживающих этот подход инструментов таких как behave [достаточно активна](https://github.com/behave/behave/pulse/monthly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

все же дополните вопрос примерами собственного выдуманного языка

"я читаю книгу" отражает текущее состояние -> welcome в конечные автоматы

"я читал книгу" статистическая информация, логи БД, история системы, активная семантика (исполняемый код) не придумывается, скорее это должен быть язык описания данных, по которым например выполняется какой-то логический вывод: типа юзер имел доступ к вот этим файлам, запланируем проверку не попортил ли он их

"я буду читать книгу" или "я хочу читать книгу" -- явно прослеживаются языки для систем планирования, управления задачами, финансового анализа и логистики: "могу крутить гайки с восьми до пяти, если меня будут возить на работу на такси", "в пакете myblin есть дыра в безопасности", "завтра нужно запустить проверку диска"

- императивное программирование -- явно в повелительном наклонении
- есть еще декларативное -- описываем что нужно получить, система разработки строит 1+ решение, удовлетворяющее заданным условиям и ограничениям (в т.ч. программирование в ограничениях: переменные имеют следующий диапазон, удовлетворяют вот такой системе уравнений, оптимизировать вот эти значения, выходной код генерировать под всю существующую матрицу mainstream платформ/языков программирования, в целевом коде можно использовать вот такие библиотеки): вроде похоже на изъявительное наклонение ?

есть еще всякое странное и смешанное декларативно/императивное

программирование через наборы правил, например описание конечного автомата в виде набора правил, условий перехода между ними, входные/выходные интерфейсы, код выполняемый при переходе/входе/выходе из состояний

языки трансформации данных: набор декларативных шаблонов входная структура -> выходная структура + функциональные части правил для прямого преобразования

языки описания грамматик для генераторов парсеров: однозначно изъявительные, исходных данных для разбора еще нет, но возможные структурные соотношения между элементами уже определяются, но зачастую каждое правило дополняется куском императивного или функционального кода: что именно надо сделать с найденными элементами, как их сгруппировать или преобразовать.

чисто логические языки типа Prolog

языки описания знаний, семантические сети, сети фреймов Минского -- включают активную часть, например описания алгоритмов в общем виде, которые могут быть применены в качестве шаблона для генерации кода, или алгоритмы высшего порядка: алгоритмы преобразования алгоритмов

Answer (score 2):

Да, скорее всего верно. Так как все (или большинство) языков программирования используют английский, то:

> Для того чтобы поставить глагол в повелительное наклонение мы используем инфинитив без частицы to.

Как видите, все глаголы в программировании используют лишь повелительное наклонение (print, show, add и тп.)

Написать программу можно используя только существительные, но вот команд в изъявительном наклонении просто нет.

Comment: подождите, как нет команд в изъявительном наклонении? А это что - "Рот закрыл!" *(я сегодня в ударе)*

Comment: @Igor, если в значении "Он рот закрыл!", то да, но вроде бы про правилам такие эмоциональные формы расцениваются как повелительные (сюда можно привести и "Всем сесть!" или "Лежать!").

Comment: @Mike, я ведь и заметил, что программ с изъявительными глаголами нет и предложил записать существительными. Но глаголов достаточно много в общем, что позволяет делать выводы.

Comment: В выражении `go to label` вряд ли `label` - глагол)

Comment: @Mike, я привел несколько в ответе (print, show, add). "goto" -- "go_to", т. е. "to" тут не указывает на инфинитив, а является предлогом ("идти **на**", "идти **в**", так "gotoScene()" = "идти **на** сцену").

Comment: @vp_arth, все правильно. Тут глагол _go_.